# php display an image from a directory

Tags: php

Im trying to display images from a directory "uploaded_files"

Source : using the code from this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aL-tOG8zGcQ&feature=plcp)

but all I get is boxes and no images [link to my project](http://ultimatemango.com/lightboxphabumdelete/phalbum/multiple/test.php)

Comment: Replace <img scr=" to <img src="

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is `<img scr="...`

Change it to `<img src="...`

Comment: How are scr and src the same?